# What is the right way to handle http Error?

Tags: angular, service, httpclient, response, interceptor

Current situation:

1. i have a service.ts which save data in the backend:

   ```
   public update(route: string, values: Array<any>): Observable<boolean> {
     let body = { values: values };

     return this.httpClient.put(route, body, {
       observe: 'response'
     })
     .map((res) => {
       let status = res.status;
       switch (status) {
           case 202:
               return true;
       }
     }, error => {
       switch (error.status) {
           case 406:
               return false;
       }
     });
   }
   ```
2. i have a http interceptor so i can append token to every request:

   ```
   public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
     return next
       .handle(request)
       .do(event => {

       })
       .catch((error: any) => {

       });
   }
   ```
3. and i have a component with a save method, where i normaly need the result:

   ```
   public save(form: FormGroup) {
     let path = '...';
     this.service.update(path, form.value)
       .subscribe(result => {
           // success
       }, error => {
           // fail
       });
   }
   ```

I dont know how to put things together.
I trigger the save method in my component and also need the result (success, error) in the component.

Right now i can only grab the result in my interceptor.
But this is the wrong place for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public update(route: string, values: Array<any>): Observable<boolean> {
  let body = { values: values };

  return this.httpClient.put(route, body, {
    observe: 'response'
  });
}
// You don't need map for httpClient
```

Then the correct way to implement `HttpInterceptor` is:

```
public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next.handle(request).do(
      (response: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        // Do stuff with success 'response instanceof HttpResponse'
      },
      (error: any) => {
        // Do stuff with error 'error instance of HttpErrorResponse'
      });
}
```